# How can I extrude a circle onto a helmet (Extrude a circle into a curved surface)?

Tags: modeling, extrude

This is my first post. I am still pretty novice and am trying to accomplish a personal project. I have a helmet where there is a pattern with circles on the helmet. I want to extrude those inward slightly.

To illustrate what I am trying to do, made two circles, snapped and shrinkwrapped them to the helmet. I imagine there is a way to make the perfect circles apply to the helmet.

I have tried making better geometry or using loop tools on the helmet itself but those solutions aren't working, and I don't want to use the knife too unless I have to. I haven't added subsurface or solidify yet just to keep things simple. [image]

Attached is a screenshot with the reference visible. I am open to and appreciate any advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need more topology than what we see here, so maybe keep a copy somewhere and apply a Subdivision Surface modifier to have a more high-poly version.

Then you can duplicate your helmet, make the copy invisible, give a *Shrinkwrap* modifier to your object with the invisible copy as *Target*, draw the circles with the knife tool, or cut off a hole, extrude and right click > *LoopTools > Circle*:

[image]

When you're good, apply the *Shrinkwrap*, extrude the circles:

[image]

Comment: I Figured it out: I create a cylinder in object mode. I snap it to the surface of the helmet and get it pointed where I want it. With the cylinder still selected, I slide it into the helmet, overlapping the geometry. I apply a boolean modifier to the cylinder, and use the helmet as the modifier's object and then apply. The cylinder is now shaped like the surface of the helmet. I then slide the cylinder into the helmet to the depth I want to "emboss/indent," and select the helmet (all in object mode still.) I then apply a boolean modifier to the helmet, sourcing the cylinder.

Comment: Basically I made the cylinder into a stamp that has the contour of the helmet.